# Can I use any install media for Windows 2012 r2 Standard for licensed VMs?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I have Windows 2012 r2 Standard.  I get two Windows virtual machines for "free."  Is that correct?  If I do get those, can I use any media?  Do I need another license to activate it?  I do not have Datacenter on the physical host.

Comment: Ask whoever you bought the license from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where did you obtain your install media from. And yes, Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard lets you activate two vOSE's with the same product key. You should get a product key with the license you purchased.